# OGRE build error -- "cannot find -lOgreMain_d.dll"

Tags: ogre

I've followed the directions here: 
http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting+Up+An+Application+-+CodeBlocks

then I get this error:

```
c:/program files/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lOgreMain_d.dll
```

I have OgreMain, OIS, OgreMain_d, OIS_d placed within my project folder. How can I fix this? :(

Answer (score 2):

This could happen primarily due to two reasons.

- The dll has not yet been compiled and created.
- In the linker settings, the dll search path or the dll name to link against is wrong.

Please check if the OgreMain_d.dll has been created in the OGRE bin folder and if so, confirm the linker search settings. Also confirm that the project is not in release build configuration, as the created dll would then be OgreMain.dll.